# Azure multiple subscriptions key vault access policies

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying to export keyvault access policies from multiple azure subscriptions to csv.
Preferably pulling those vault names & sub ids from an input csv and looping through it.
Searching around I found solutions but they all use hardcoded vault names..
I hope this makes sense..
Will appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi,
It will be helpful if you get started coding your solution following the examples you found out and then share a snippet of your code asking how to make the vault name dynamic, perhaps being read from an array of Strings. You can hook later the csv file.
Then you can change the title of the question.
Export multiple azure subscriptions key vault access policies using variable hard code vault names.
Hope that helps you get more answers.

Comment: @cloudraven  I rather spare you the bother posting my trial and error but the two blocks below are what I base my efforts upon.  $vaults = @()
$Subscriptions = Get-AzureRmSubscription
foreach ($vault in $Subscriptions) {
    Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzureRmContext
    $vaults += Get-AzureRmKeyVault
}
$vaults | Ft     On this one I can loop through subs and vaults but cannot export the access policies....

Comment: @cloudraven  $x= (get-AzureRmKeyVault).VaultName
$keyVault = Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $x
$accessPolicies = $keyVault.AccessPolicies | select DisplayName, PermissionsToCertificatesStr, PermissionsToKeysStr, PermissionsToSecretsStr | Export-Csv v.csv      On this I can pull access policies but only for the active sub Im logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the script below, it works fine on my side.

```
$subs = Get-AzureRmSubscription
foreach($sub in $subs){
    Set-AzureRmContext -Subscription $sub.Id -Tenant $sub.TenantId
    $vaults = Get-AzureRmKeyVault
    foreach($vault in $vaults){
        $policies = (Get-AzureRmKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $vault.ResourceGroupName -VaultName $vault.VaultName).AccessPolicies
        $policies | select DisplayName, PermissionsToCertificatesStr, PermissionsToKeysStr, PermissionsToSecretsStr | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\policies.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

The `policies.csv` file will be like:

[image: policies.csv]

**Update**:

If you want to include the keyvault name, try the script below.

```
$subs = Get-AzureRmSubscription
foreach($sub in $subs){
    Set-AzureRmContext -Subscription $sub.Id -Tenant $sub.TenantId
    $vaults = Get-AzureRmKeyVault
    foreach($vault in $vaults){
        $policies = (Get-AzureRmKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $vault.ResourceGroupName -VaultName $vault.VaultName).AccessPolicies
        foreach($policy in $policies){
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
            KeyVaultName = $vault.VaultName
            DisplayName = $policy.DisplayName
            PermissionsToCertificatesStr = $policy.PermissionsToCertificatesStr
            PermissionsToKeysStr = $policy.PermissionsToKeysStr
            PermissionsToSecretsStr = $policy.PermissionsToSecretsStr
            }
        $obj |  Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\policies1.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
       }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great Joy, thank you. Will it be easy to also add the keyvault name?